# My iCal isn't picking up invitations from iCloud. What can I do?

Tags: icloud, ical

My boyfriend and I shared a MobileMe family account with our own email addresses. We also had our calendars shared. To keep each other in the loop, we occasionally invited each other to events. Everything worked perfectly. Then we moved to iCloud and things aren't as smooth. We recently realized the invitations he sent to me weren't showing up in my iCal. They were still showing up online at iCloud.com (where I can accept/decline) and in the iCal app on my iPhone 4, but only as a dotted event on the day, not in the Invitation tab. On my iPhone, I can accept/decline if I click on the event. Since I have his calendar showing in my iCal on my Mac, I can see the events I'm invited to, but cannot accept/decline there.

The inconsistencies are throwing me for a loop. I've logged out of iCloud and relogged in, deleted the calendar from my Mac and resynced. I've made sure the default calendar is my personal calendar. I've made sure my address card is updated and correct. Same issues. Any thoughts or help?

Answer (score 1):

How are the settings in iCal? Meaning have you added the Cloud calendar to your accounts? In iCal, under preferences, under accounts you have to make sure that your iCloud account is added on there. If it's not, try it. Go to add, select iCloud as the account type, sign in and so on and so forth. If this is already done. I'm at a lost and will need to look into it more.

Comment: Yes, everything is added in iCal and also added and turned on in the System Settings > iCloud.